# Is there any other way of setting up Unreal Engine 4 for Android Without Codeworks

Tags: android, nvidia, unreal-engine4

My question is very simple Is there any other way of setting up Unreal Engine 4 for Android Without Nvidia Codeworks because when I install codewords it messes with an environment variables which in turn causes lots of errors in the android studio and some random stuff starts happening either emulator won't work etc.

I am trying all the stuff on and off for over a year as I really want to try UE4 for Android development to see whether it is as good as unity or not.

If there is a workaround using Nvidia codewords please let me know.

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Ofcours,

It isn't that harder either. You can download the Android sdk yourself by using:
https://developer.android.com/studio/

Scroll down until you see "Command line tools only"
Then install java se etc.

And in unreal open project settings -> Android SDK

There you can fill in the paths.

Comment: Thanx for reply, I did exactly that many times but it doesn't work more specifically I cannot accept SDK License in project setting->Platforms->Android Even though I clicked on it multiple times.